# The motivation of weak topology in the definition of CW complex

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

## Background

A CW complex is a Hausdorff space and it is the union of its some of its subsets called cells, and cells are homeomorphic images in $X$ of some closed $k$-balls.

The weak topology of a CW complex X is defined as the topology having the property that a subset of $X$ is closed if and only if it is closed in each cell of $X$.

## The question

What is the motivation of requiring that the topology is weak? What is, if $X$ has more closed sets then in this definition, and what is if it has less. And why are closed sets are generally used in this definition, why not open sets? (I saw in some places this definition with open sets. Is it an error, or it is an equivalent definition?)

Comment: One correction: Cells are not necessarily homeomorphic to a closed $k$-ball. If $\Phi_α$ is the characteristic map from a ball $D_α^k$ to $X$, then $\Phi_α$ could send two different points in $∂D^k$ to the same image. It restricts to homeomorphism $\operatorname{int}(D^k)\approx e_\alpha$, though, where $e_\alpha$ is an *open $k$-cell*, and the space $X$ is the disjoint union of open cells. One should maybe call $\Phi_\alpha(D^k)$ a *closed* $k$-cell, to distinguish it from the open cells.

Comment: A motivation for this topology is that we may define a map from $X$ to some space $Y$ by giving the function on each individual closed cells of $X$. Then if these functions agree where closed cells intersect and if each function is continuous, so is the map $X\to Y$.

Comment: To follow on with Stefan's comment, the weak topology allows the inductive construction of continuous maps $X \to Y$, that is,  by induction on the skeleta $X^n$ of the CW-complex $X$. Similarly, using the natural cellular structure on $X \times I$ it allows the inductive construction of homotopies. These are crucial techniques in algebraic topology. .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an answer to the motivation for the definition of CW-complex. The main one is given by the following from Section $5$ of Whitehead's paper Combinatorial Homotopy I.

Let $K$  be  a  CW-complex.

(A)  A  map $f: X \to Y$   of a  closed  (open)  subset, $ X \subset K$ in  any  space, $Y$,  is  continuous   provided $f| X \cap \bar{e}$   is  continuous  for each cell  $e \in K$.

Nowadays we might do it a bit differently and say that the topology on $K$ is defined so that this property holds. This can be done by defining the $n$ skeleton $K^n$ to be obtained from the $(n-1)$-skeleton $K^{n-1}$  by attaching $n$-cells $e^n_\lambda$ by maps $a_\lambda: S^{n-1} \to K^{n-1}$. Then define the topology on $K$ so that a map $f: K \to X$ is continuous if and only if the restriction of $f$ to  $K^n \to Y$ is continuous for all $n \geqslant 0$.

This accords with the modern view that topology is "about" the category of spaces and continuous maps, and to construct these maps  we often use the universal properties of pushouts and colimits (and for other examples, pullbacks and limits).

A gentle introduction to adjunction spaces and finite cell complexes is given in the book [Topology and Groupoids](http://groupoids.org.uk/topgpds.html).

Ioan James once said at Oxford that Whitehead took a year to prove the product property (H), which is now subsumed under the notion of [convenient category of spaces](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/convenient+category+of+topological+spaces).

His motivation can also be seen in his highly original 1941 papers in the Annals of Math, referred to in CHI. The latter paper, and CHII and Simple Homotopy Types, constitute a rewrite and extension of these essentially prewar papers.