# Definition of CW complex: weak topology vs quotient

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

In the definition of a CW complex we construct a topological space by gluing  $n$-cells to the $n-1$-skeleton, and then we give to it another topology (it already has one: the one given by the gluing operation which is a quotient topology) choosing a particular family of closed sets as fundamental covering (or equivalently the initial topology given by the  characteristic maps).

I imagine that the two topologies (the quotient and the weak one) are different (otherwise why call it "weak"? It would be enough to define the CW complex as a gluing of cells), but I would make good use of an example. Can anyone help me?
Thanks

Comment: CW complexes are colimits of its cells in Top.

Comment: Have you seen https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1463652/the-motivation-of-weak-topology-in-the-definition-of-cw-complex

Comment: You give the n-skeleton the quotient topology, which you have to if you want to use the word "gluing" at all. Then if there are cells in every dimension, this process never stops, so you need to give your CW complex then the weak (colimit) topology, to talk about it as having a topology at all.

These two UMPs are for entirely different reasons / happening at different "locations" in the construction process.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The two topologies are exactly the same, as you can easily prove by induction on $n$.  Indeed, supposing the two topologies are the same on the $(n-1)$-skeleton $X^{n-1}$, the quotient topology on $X^n$ has the property that a map out of it is continuous iff its restriction to $X^{n-1}$ is continuous and its composition with the characteristic map of each $n$-cell is continuous.  But by induction, the restriction to $X^{n-1}$ is continuous iff the composition with the characteristic map of each cell of dimension $<n$ is continuous.  This shows the quotient topology has the same universal property as the weak topology.

So there is no need to refer to the weak topology induced by the cells in defining a CW-complex, and some authors do not do so (for instance, Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology* just defines the topology as the quotient topology).  For infinite-dimensional CW-complexes, you can define the topology as the colimit topology with respect to the inclusions of the skeleta, where the skeleta are inductively given the quotient topology.

As for why the topology is called "weak", "weak topology" is sometimes used as a synonym for "colimit topology" (but beware in functional analysis it is instead used as a synonym for "limit topology"!).  In particular, for instance, the weak topology on an infinite CW-complex is typically much finer than other natural topologies that may exist.  For instance, a wedge of countably infinitely many circles can be given a topology by identifying it with the [Hawaiian earring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawaiian_earring), a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$, but the CW-complex topology is much finer than the Hawaiian earring topology.

Comment: This question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3234052 also confused me. What is the definition of the initial topology? In my opinion it is this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_topology, but that does not fit to topologizing  CW-complexes. In fact, they have the final topology.

Comment: Huh apparently my usage of initial/final is backwards; I'll fix that.  It's confusing because it's the opposite of what you would expect from their categorical meaning ("initial" ought to mean colimit, not limit!).

Comment: You are right, but notation is not always logical. Especially the "weak topology" isn't really weak, but stronger than other topologies (at least if we agree that "stronger" is a synonym for "finer").

Comment: See Lee Mosher's comment to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3245688.

Comment: +1, but it looks like Hatcher actually *does* explicitly define CW complexes using the weak topology on p. 5 and in the appendix on p. 519 (in both the 2016 printing I own, and in the version of "Algebraic topology" I retrieved from Hatcher's website today.) However, on p. 519 he does say this: "Note that condition (3) [the weak topology condition] is superfluous when $X$ is finite-dimensional, so that $X = X^n$ for some $n$."

Comment: @MatthewKvalheim: Hatcher defines CW complexes as having the weak topology induced by their finite-dimensional skeleta, rather than the weak topology induced by the individual cells.